# When document.getElementById() doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I have some JavaScript that obtains elements by ID from an HTML document.

In one particular scenario, the document.getElementById(idString) method returns null in IE8 compatibility mode, however the jQuery equivalent works. I need to work out why the native call isn't working.

Here's an example:

```
var myId = "e_" + someId;
var myNativeDiv = document.getElementById(myId);
var myjQueryDiv = $("#" + myId);
alert(myNativeDiv + " - " + myjQueryDiv); // alerts "null - [Object object]"
```

I've checked that `myId` is unique in the document.

Any avenues to investigate appreciated.

---

Update - actually, `myjQueryDiv` is also empty, but I guess jQuery makes it not null. However, the call `parentDom.find("#" + myId);` does return the correct element, where parentDom is an ancestor of the element I need to find.

Comment: Could you post some HTML to replicate "one particular scenario" where this error occurs?

Comment: may be due to the type of myId

Comment: Well, sometimes the problem is that it page didn't load, but jquery part was executed when it was loaded. Try using, $(document).ready(), or equivalent

Comment: I'm using document.ready to trigger the code. I'm afraid I can't supply the HTML document I'm using - I'm looking more for general things to check.

Comment: I find that I can get the element using document.getElementById(...) using the IE8 dev tools script 'Run script', copying the id from the alert. So it seems like the element is not available at the point this code executes, but it executes in jQuery document.ready... weird

Comment: Copying the id from the alert? Is this an encoding thing, that your id string is strangely malformed or misencoded?

Comment: No, just copying from the alert box I issued to make sure I got it exactly right.

Comment: Facepalm! OK, I know what the problem is now. Clue - the fact that a JQuery find by id *from an ancestor element* works fine, but neither JQuery or native methods can find the same element from the *document*... what other JQuery operation, executed prior, could explain that? First with the correct answer wins the points.

Comment: You removed an element from the DOM, so it's not in the document, but still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here's the answer.

I had previously `detach()`ed an ancestor element, so jQuery find could see the element by ID when executed from an ancestor element in the detached fragment.

Of course both jQuery find with no context and the native method correctly did not return the element, as it was not at that point part of the `document`.

Answer (score 5):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx)...

> In IE8 Standards mode, `getElementById` performs a case-sensitive match on the `ID` attribute only. In IE7 Standards mode and previous modes, this method performs a case-insensitive match on both the ID and NAME attributes, which might produce unexpected results.

It's possible that your code relies on one of these behaviours.

---

jQuery wraps its results in a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), so that things like `$(".unused-class").remove()` don't raise errors. You can check the `.length` or value at `[0]` to see if it actually matched any elements.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me

- [your code](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/fa679.php)
- [added innerHTML & html()](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/5ca4e.php)